# Filter an array by value in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to return the values of array if its values contains a specific string

```
var names=  [
    ["FCFEDA", "Moon Glow"],
    ["FCFFE7", "China Ivory"],
    ["FCFFF9", "Ceramic"],
    ["FD0E35", "Torch Green"],
    ["FD5B78", "Wild Watermelon"],
    ["FD7B33", "Crusta Green"]

];
var color_swatches = [];
var result = $.grep(names, function(v,i) {
    if(v[1].indexOf("Green") > -1){
        return v[0];
    }
})
color_swatches.push(result);
alert(color_swatches);
```

results in

```
    FD0E35, Torch Green,FD7B33, Crusta Green
```

I want exactly like this

```
    ["#FD0E35","#FD7B33"]
```

Take note that the result should inside the square brackets and with qoutes. Only contains hex not the equivalent name and # added.

Any ideas?

Comment: An alternate: unless you need to support some ancient browsers you can skip jQuery and use vanilla JS: var result = names.filter(function(v) {
    return v[1].indexOf("Green") > -1;
}).map(function(w) {
    return "#" + w[0];
});

Comment: You don't need jQuery to achieve this. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41178944/652669). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.grep()` function «Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function» [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

In other words, in your code it returns the "sub-array" into `result`.

Try using a simple loop like this:

```js
    var names=  [
        ["FCFEDA", "Moon Glow"],
        ["FCFFE7", "China Ivory"],
        ["FCFFF9", "Ceramic"],
        ["FD0E35", "Torch Green"],
        ["FD5B78", "Wild Watermelon"],
        ["FD7B33", "Crusta Green"]

    ];
    var color_swatches = [];

    for(i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        if(names[i][1].indexOf("Green") > -1){
            color_swatches.push( names[i][0] );
        }
    }
    //color_swatches.push(result);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(color_swatches));
```

**Notice** that I used `JSON.strignify()` only to see the content of the `color_swatches` array in console.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this.

```js
var names=  [
    ["FCFEDA", "Moon Glow"],
    ["FCFFE7", "China Ivory"],
    ["FCFFF9", "Ceramic"],
    ["FD0E35", "Torch Green"],
    ["FD5B78", "Wild Watermelon"],
    ["FD7B33", "Crusta Green"]

];
var color_swatches = [];
names.forEach(item => {
 if(item[1].indexOf("Green") > -1){
        color_swatches.push('#' + item[0]);
    }
});
console.log(color_swatches);
console.log(JSON.stringify(color_swatches));
```

Comment: I need exactly like this    ["#FD0E35","#FD7B33"]

Comment: Where is the difference to mine?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map function to transform the `color_swatches` array. In the map function, you can pick the first item and add a `#`. Before the alert, add:

```
color_swatches = $.map(color_swatches[0], function(index, color_swatch) {
    return "#" + color_swatch[0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript functions [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var names = [
  ["FCFEDA", "Moon Glow"],
  ["FCFFE7", "China Ivory"],
  ["FCFFF9", "Ceramic"],
  ["FD0E35", "Torch Green"],
  ["FD5B78", "Wild Watermelon"],
  ["FD7B33", "Crusta Green"]
]

console.log(names.filter(n => n[1].includes('Green')).map(n => `#${n[0]}`))

// ["#FD0E35","#FD7B33"]
```